# Remove an empty row from a CSV

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have a csv made like this:

```
16;SILCOMP1;1;;;;;A;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
32;SILCOMP1;1;;;;A;;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
64;SILCOMP1;1;;A;;;;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
128;SILCOMP1;1;A;;;;;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3;SILCOMP1;2;;;;;;;;;;B;A;niente;niente
5;SILCOMP1;2;;;;;;;;B;;;A;niente;niente
```

basically I want to create a code that automaticaly recognize the row ";;;;" the one between 128 and 3 and delete or skip it.
After moving each raw of the csv into a data_array,
I've tried to use the

```
len(data_array[i]) == 0
```

but it seems that even if the raw is made by ";" it is not empty. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried `set(data_array[i]) == ';'`? If this is not a homework, try using pandas to make life easier.

Comment: What is `data_array`, and how is it related to this file?

Comment: an example of data_array is given  on the top.... I've already extract from the CSV the array (so called data_array)

Comment: Have you tried to read the csv wiht pandas ([pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))? Then you can easilly drop the empty row (with [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html))

Comment: Read the file like `data = [row for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=";") if any(item != "" for item in row)]`?

Comment: ciao, well I have used csv and numpy library so I prefer to continue with these...any solution? Timus I've tried your solution and It doesn't work. as well for Epsi95 solution

Comment: Worked for me with the sample data you've provided?

Comment: this is what it printed out Timus "[['C'], [':'], ['\\'], ['p'], ['y'], ['t'], ['h'], ['o'], ['n'], ['\\'], ['T'], ['a'], ['b'], ['e'], ['l'], ['l'], ['a'], ['_'], ['4'], ['_'], ['d'], ['i'], ['s'], ['c'], ['o'], ['n'], ['n'], ['e'], ['s'], ['s'], ['i'], ['o'], ['n'], ['i'], ['.'], ['c'], ['s'], ['v']]" no idea of where these values come from.

Comment: `file` is meant as a file handler, not the filename string: `file = open(filename, "r")`

Comment: I've replaced the "File" with the path where the .csv is located... is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a file `data.csv` like

```
16;SILCOMP1;1;;;;;A;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
32;SILCOMP1;1;;;;A;;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
64;SILCOMP1;1;;A;;;;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
128;SILCOMP1;1;A;;;;;;;;;;;GO_SLAVE_10;niente
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
3;SILCOMP1;2;;;;;;;;;;B;A;niente;niente
5;SILCOMP1;2;;;;;;;;B;;;A;niente;niente
```

this

```
import csv

with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    data = [
        row for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
        if any(item != "" for item in row)
    ]
```

does produce the following `data`:

```
[['16', 'SILCOMP1', '1', '', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'GO_SLAVE_10', 'niente']
 ['32', 'SILCOMP1', '1', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'GO_SLAVE_10', 'niente']
 ['64', 'SILCOMP1', '1', '', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'GO_SLAVE_10', 'niente']
 ['128', 'SILCOMP1', '1', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'GO_SLAVE_10', 'niente']
 ['3', 'SILCOMP1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'B', 'A', 'niente', 'niente']
 ['5', 'SILCOMP1', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'B', '', '', 'A', 'niente', 'niente']]
```